# How to round a date to the closest month and then add one month in sql lite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to add a month to data that I've rounded to the floored month.

In postgresql, its simple with code that looks like with

```
with month as 
(select '2020-01-15' as n_month)

select
   date_trunc('month', n_month) as floored_month,
   dateadd('month', 1, date_trunc('month', n_month)) as floored_month_plus_one
from month
```

I'd like to achieve this same table with sql lite

This is my code so far

```
with month as 
(select '2020-01-15' as n_month)

select 
     strftime('%Y-%m', n_month) as floored_month,
     date(strftime('%Y-%m', n_month), '+1 months') as floored_month_plus_one
from month
```

But unfortunately that gives me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for concatenations.
You can do it with the function [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and the modifiers `'start of month'` and `'+1 month'`:

```
with month as (select '2020-01-15' as n_month)
select date(n_month,  'start of month') as floored_month,
       date(n_month,  'start of month', '+1 month') as floored_month_plus_one
from month
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fe9bf4dc004332993b7f2ea02ae1ce44).
Results:

```
> floored_month | floored_month_plus_one
> :------------ | :---------------------
> 2020-01-01    | 2020-02-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the day component to follow your method for doing this.  So:

```
with month as (
      select '2020-01-15' as n_month
     )
select strftime('%Y-%m', n_month) as floored_month,
       date(strftime('%Y-%m', n_month) || '-01', '+1 months') as floored_month_plus_one
from month
```

Comment: Another way is to use ` strftime('%Y-%m-%d', n_month, 'start of month')` and then use dateadd on that value